# Exceção ao deletar diretório usando FileUtils.deleteDirectory

Tags: java, apache, arquivo

O diretório possui 6 arquivos dentro dele. A exceção que ocorre é java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: tmp\umDosArquivos. Manualmente, consigo excluir todos os arquivos e o diretório. Usei o método canWrite, de File, para ver se havia algum lock, mas sempre retorna  true. As permissões de acesso aos arquivos também estão corretas. O que pode estar acontecendo?

```
File tmpDir = new File("tmp");
if (tmpDir.exists()) {
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tmpDir);
}
```

Comment: Posto o codigo que você está usando para fazer a exclusão.

Comment: Postei o código. A exceção ocorre em FileUtils.deleteDirectory

Comment: O comando File.delete, para diretório, ou no caso File.eleteDirectory não está claro se isso é também verdade, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html, só vai funcionar para diretórios vazios. E sempre no java, passe o full path. Veja este artigo, alias os artigos deste site são muito bons: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-delete-directory-in-java/

Comment: Pelo que entendi, File.deleteDirectory deveria funcionar, pois diz que deleta recursivamente. O código do artigo funcionou e está muito bom. Obrigado!

Comment: @user1902062 publique uma resposta com a solução encontrada.